# meaning of enclosed parallel region

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

These days I'm learning to use openmp for parallel operating the former codes, but when I'm reading some resources on the internet, I get confused about some concept, like **enclosed parallel region**. I'm not a native speaker in English, and I don't major in computer science, so I'm not sure what's the meaning of it. The following is a copy of https://software.intel.com/zh-cn/node/512042 that explaining the private clause. So my question is what's the meaning of **enclosed parallel construct**, can I understand it as nest parallel construct? If not, what's the difference between this two concepts? If there is an example, that will be the best! Thank you for all who answer my question.

> Variables in a list can appear in other clauses as follows:
>
> Variables that appear in a PRIVATE, FIRSTPRIVATE, or REDUCTION clause
>   in a parallel construct can also appear in a PRIVATE clause in an
>   enclosed parallel, task, or worksharing construct.
>
> Variables that appear in a PRIVATE or FIRSTPRIVATE clause in a task
>   construct can also appear in a PRIVATE clause in an enclosed parallel
>   or task construct.
>
> Variables that appear in a PRIVATE, FIRSTPRIVATE, LASTPRIVATE, or
>   REDUCTION clause in a worksharing construct can also appear in a
>   PRIVATE clause in an enclosed parallel or task construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is what's the meaning of enclosed parallel construct,
>   can I understand it as nest parallel construct?

Yes, your understanding is correct.  An enclosed parallel construct is nested inside an enclosing parallel construct -- so the enclosing parallel construct is more extensive than the enclosed.

If you write your code in one long source file then the enclosed construct is likely to be indented further than the enclosing construct.

Comment: Thank you so much @High Performance Mark. I type a fairly easy code and it works. May I ask some other questions? If there only appears a !$OMP PARALLEL directive, does it mean that every thread do the following block respectively? Only if it's combined with some worksharing directives, will the code become parallel executed?